# Stata: subinstr not working on hyphens, any ideas

Tags: stata

I am attempting to use the `subinstr()` command to remove hyphens in some names.  Unfortunately, individual hyphens, and names starting with hyphens, are not being removed. (There is a reason for having both: "`-`something" is more specific than "something", and I don't want to accidentally remove an important part of a name.)

Are there any extra things I'd need to add to get the hyphens removed?

code sample  (the full code would be too long to add here)

```
append using "2011 Death", force;
append using "2012 Death", force;
duplicates drop;
replace ID = subinstr(ID,"HLTH","HEALTH",.);
replace ID = subinstr(ID,"CORPORATION","",.);
replace ID = subinstr(ID,"ASSOCIATIONINC","",.);
replace ID = subinstr(ID,"-P&MED","PITALANDMED",.);
replace ID = subinstr(ID,"-HIGHLANDSMEDICALCENTER","",.);
replace ID = subinstr(ID,"-","",.);
(more along similar lines)
```

The `"-highlandmedicalcenter"`, `"-P&MED"` and `"-"` are not removed, as in the names with something`-highlandsmedicalcenter` still exist after processing. The first three are. I am not sure about the `-p$med`.

Comment: `subinstr()` in Stata is a function, not a command. Functions and commands are distinct in Stata.

Answer (score 1):

The following example using your code works for me. My only explanation for your experience is that perhaps your data have en-dashes or em-dashes rather than hyphens.

```
. input str30 s1

                                 s1
  1. "HLTH"
  2. "CORPORATION"
  3. "ASSOCIATIONINC"
  4. "-P&MED"
  5. "-HIGHLANDSMEDICALCENTER"
  6. "-GNXL"
  7. end

. clonevar s2 = s1

. replace s2 = subinstr(s2,"HLTH","HEALTH",.)
(1 real change made)

. replace s2 = subinstr(s2,"CORPORATION","",.)
(1 real change made)

. replace s2 = subinstr(s2,"ASSOCIATIONINC","",.)
(1 real change made)

. replace s2 = subinstr(s2,"-P&MED","PITALANDMED",.)
(1 real change made)

. replace s2 = subinstr(s2,"-HIGHLANDSMEDICALCENTER","",.)
(1 real change made)

. replace s2 = subinstr(s2,"-","",.)
(1 real change made)

. list, clean

                            s1            s2  
  1.                      HLTH        HEALTH  
  2.               CORPORATION                
  3.            ASSOCIATIONINC                
  4.                    -P&MED   PITALANDMED  
  5.   -HIGHLANDSMEDICALCENTER                
  6.                     -GNXL          GNXL  

.
```

Comment: en-dashes or em-dashes--what are these?

Comment: Dashes are longer than hyphens, commonly created by Microsoft applications with autocorrect running, that change things--like this--to things—like this—whether that's what you wanted or not.

Comment: Let me add that my example was run using Stata 13.1. If you are using Stata 14, it supports Unicode, which might add further options for confusing things.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of hyphen it was, but copy/pasting the hyphen from the original excel file solved the problem.  (Seems obvious now, but at least the problem/possible solution/info is on here for anyone in the future.)  Thank you.